# Performance hit when assigning WorkSheet.UsedRange to variable in PowerShell Excel Automation

Tags: performance, excel, powershell, interop, com-interop

I'm new to working with COM objects and I have read what I can to get an understanding on the subject, but I can't seem to figure out this behavior. I have a suspicion that there is something obvious going on under the covers that I just don't understand. I'm automating the processing of IIS logs with LogParser and building reports in Excel. I started with the following block of code in a PowerShell Module I wrote to get the last column used:

```
$used = $WorkSheet.usedRange
$lastCell = $used.SpecialCells($xlCellTypeLastCell)
if($Axis -eq 'Row'){$tmpLast = $lastCell.Row}
if($Axis -eq 'Column'){$tmpLast = $lastCell.Column}
Release-Ref $used
```

$WorkSheet is a valid worksheet object. This code block worked great on small worksheets, but as the size of the worksheets grew execution would take longer and longer. If the sheet was too large it would hang altogether. Additionally, it would start to hang other applications I was trying to use and I just ended up waiting for it to complete before I could use my computer. Its not a resource issue as I am running this on a i7 with 24GB of RAM. When I stepped through the code in the PowerShell ISE (2.0), I found that it was hanging when I stepped into `Release-Ref $used`. I'm not sure why it would hang on that particular line only for large worksheets. Large is defined by ~25K rows & 15-20 columns, which isn't that large for what Excel can handle. Here is the Release-Ref function:

```
function Release-Ref{
[CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName='Single')]
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=0,ParameterSetName='Single')]
    [System.__ComObject]$ref,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=0,ParameterSetName='Array')]
    [System.__ComObject[]]$refs,

    [Switch]$Final
)
if($Final){
    [System.GC]::Collect()
    [System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
}
if($PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName -eq 'Array'){
    foreach($ref in $refs){
        if($ref -ne $null){
            [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::FinalReleaseComObject($ref) `
                | Out-Null
        }
    }
}else{
    if($ref -ne $null){
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::FinalReleaseComObject($ref) `
            | Out-Null
    }
}
}
```

When stepping through this function, I also noticed that it would also lag on `if($ref -ne $null)`. I structured both the code block in question and the function based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158706/how-to-properly-clean-up-excel-interop-objects) which stated "Never use 2 dots with COM objects" and showed how to properly clean up the Excel process following Mike Rosenblom's response. I originally had issues with the Excel process being left over at the end of the automation, and went through following this principle as best I could. I ended up getting Excel to close out properly, but the execution was taking 20-40mins for some reports.

I finally moved to the following block of code replacing the previous:

```
$lastCell = $WorkSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells($xlCellTypeLastCell)
if($Axis -eq 'Row'){$tmpLast = $lastCell.Row}
if($Axis -eq 'Column'){$tmpLast = $lastCell.Column}
```

I am now violating the 2 dot principle, but this removed the call that was hanging and now the reports run in a couple of minutes. Excel is still closing out, but not as immediate as before. I'm concerned that Excel might start sticking around occasionally now, but the performance improvement is worth it at the moment.

My questions come down to:

1. Should I be concern that Excel will fail to close in the future based on violating the 2 dot principle in that section of code?
2. And, what explains the performance hit for "large" worksheets on the original code?

I wouldn't have guessed that it would be the call to the Release-Ref function that would be slow, but something inside of it as I am not overly familiar with the Garbage Collection process.